# How can I choose what account is used when accessing GitHub from VSCode?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, personal-access-token

VS Code has a builtin extension `GitHub Authentication` that manages creation of a GitHub Personal Access Token and automatic logins.

However, if you are using more then one GitHub account, the extension might try generating a PAT for the wrong account, resulting in an access denied.

```
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
remote: Permission to MyAccount/repo.git denied to OtherAccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MyAccount/repo.git/': Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remedy is to abort the web session started by `GitHub Authentication`, and then in the message bar of VSCode, click on `GitHub Authentication` to trigger the manual failback PAT handling.

First make sure you have a current PAT created for repo access for MyAccount on GitHub.  Then copy the PAT and enter it VSCode when prompted.